# Table Storage - Intermittent Service unavailable or Table Not found exception

Tags: c#, exception, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have created a console app to remove some data from table storage. The code is a follows:

```
do
    {
        TableQuerySegment<TableEntity> resultSegment = await cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, token);
        token = resultSegment.ContinuationToken;

        foreach (TableEntity entity in resultSegment.Results)
        {
            TableOperation deleteOperation = TableOperation.Delete(entity);
            await cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(deleteOperation);
        }
    } while (token != null);
```

Since the data is in millions, it takes some time to run and it throws intermittent `Service Unavailable` or `Not Found` exception. I am not able to find a reason. Any help!

Comment: Could you tell me how you connect Azure table storage? is that you use SAS token? If you use it, I think it may be expired.

Comment: No I am connecting using connection string. Full code here - https://gist.github.com/garima2510/dbc5bd1e0b8c21544acc04c811683b62